# How can I create a standalone static library using QApplication?

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries

I would like to create a standalone static library with *Qt*, using the `QApplication` class.

So to do that I use a *PIMPL*, because I wouldn't like to expose any of the *Qt* classes.

My private implementation looks as simple as this:

```
class Implementation : public QApplication {
public:
    Implementation(int argc, char *argv[]) :
        QApplication(argc, argv)
    {

    }
};
```

But whenever I try to initiate the library from my test application I get all there errors:

```
undefined reference to `QApplication::metaObject() const'
```

Yes! It does make sense. I am getting those because the test application doesn't have any references to *Qt*'s `QApplication` class.

So how do I use *Qt* and specifically the `QApplication` class in my library and still being able to use it in **Plain C++ Projects**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class definition is missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro and/or your build system has not run the `moc` on your file(s).

Furthermore, willing to use the `QApplication` class in a **library** is not a typical design pattern. What made you choose `QApplication` here?

Comment: I would like to use QWidgets and QPainter, to create a simple drawing lib. I don't know whether it's connected to the issue, but I still get an `undefined reference to _imp___ZN12QApplicationC2ERiPPci1` and also another one `undefined reference to vtable for SimpleOpenDrawerImplementation`. Could you offer an advice on solving that?

Comment: Make sure you have [invoked ``moc``](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#moc) and are linking with the resulting object files. That's the cause of your linker errors.
As of the library-vs-QApplication, a typical approach is to delegate instantiating the QApplication to the library user. There can only be a single QApplication instance per process.

Comment: I added `#include "implementation.moc"` to the end of the file. Now I get lots of new `undefined reference` errors, including `undefined reference to 'non-virtual thunk to ...'`